# Running Memory Size

Tags: android, eclipse, memory

I have an app which consists of a service and some activities. The running size of app reported by settings is around 15MB which seems excessive to me. Eclipse MAT reports total size as only 2.2 MB in Leak Suspects. My questions are:-

1. Is my service running size actually only 2.2 MB ?
2. Is the 15 MB reported by settings something to do with backstack of activities and therefore I need not be worried ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use this code hope this help you

```
    MemoryInfo mi = new MemoryInfo();
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
    long availableMegs = mi.availMem / 1048576L;
    Log.e("Avaliable start", " "+availableMegs);
```

Comment: public long availMem --The total available memory on the system. This is the documentation on availMem. But I need info on my app not on the system. Thanks anyway.

Comment: What he said has noting nothing nothing... to do with it! Anyone else?